# Accessing values in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my dictionary:

> {'request': [YearCount( year=2005, count=646179 ), YearCount( year=2006, count=677820 ), YearCount(   year=2007, count=697645 ), YearCount( year=2008, count=795265 )], 'wandered': [YearCount( year=2005, count=83769 ), YearCount( year=2006, count=87688 ), YearCount( year=2007, count=108634 ), YearCount( year=2008, count=171015 )], 'airport': [YearCount( year=2007, count=175702 ), YearCount( year=2008, count=173294 )]}

I need help figuring out how to access the YearCount - count value. Because I'm trying to find the letter frequency of each word such as 'request', 'wandered', and 'airport'. I count the total number of
each letter occurring in all the words in the input data set. This number is then divided by the total
number of letters in all the words.

Answer (score 0):

If that's your dictionary then you can access a list of `YearCount` objects by doing:

```
objects = my_dict['request']
```

You can then iterate over the list and access the `.count` values:

```
for year_count in objects:
    print(year_count.count)
```

You can also add them up to get the total count for that word:

```
total = 0
for year_count in objects:
    total += year_count.count
print(total)
```

To display up all word occurrences you can do:

```
for word, year_counts in my_dict.items():
    total = 0
    for year_count in year_counts:
        total += year_count.count
    print(word, total)
```

Comment: Instead of : objects = my_dict['request']   how do I access the counts in general without stating a specific key, because my dictionary won't look exactly like this structure every time

Comment: @Adam: in that case you'll need to iterate over all the keys in the dictionary: `for word in my_dict.items():`. So it would be a for loop inside another for loop. See my updated answer.